# Is Lazy keywords harmful for memory or performance?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I know funda of Lazy keyword. It will be calculate initial value after first usage and It will be calculated once after that will behave like normal keyword. There are so many answers/tutorial available but..

I just want to know that if I use multiple lazy keyword like 50 to 100 or more then It will be harmful for memory or performance?

Comment: no its not.lazy means initialize variable where you want yo use it not at first place but you should not use lazy everywhere

Comment: "not use lazy everywhere" mean can you please more clear me?

Comment: `lazy` by itself won't affect performance at all. `lazy` is just syntactic sugar for something that has been always used in programming. Usually it is used to improve the performance - delay initialization until the object is needed therefore avoid long initialization times. Usually that means better distribution of heavy tasks over the time. It's not the best solution always but in most situations it is.

Comment: means when you lazy it transfer control to variable initialize it transfer control back where it is used so if you use it every where then it will be tedious task though it is memory efficient in short it will reduce memory complexity but increase time complexity if you use it unneccesarily

Comment: Ok got now got it.. It will not be got affect but it's not good habit to use unnecessary Lazy var

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just want to know that if I use multiple lazy keyword like 50 to 100 or more then It will be harmful for memory or performance?

To the extent that it affects anything at all, it could be beneficial to memory and performance. 
Lazy is not about the amount of anything. It is about when something happens. “Pay me now or pay me later.” Except that with lazy, you might never pay at all.

By the way, all global variables and static variables are lazy. So you probably use lazy all the time without even knowing.

Comment: https://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/11/global-variables-in-swift-are-not-variables/

Answer (score 1):

Lazy will not affect performance at all. The variable will remain a normal variable that have the same initialization performance.
The lazy variable is just a variable that is initialized on the first usage. So you must use it if you think that you need to use the variable after the init of its class because, maybe, you need to have all the not-lazy variable initialized to get the lazy-var value

Answer (score 1):

Lazy means it will only create the instance only when you need it. so it will save the memory or performance especially when the instance is large or takes long time to init.